# angularjs directive + apply scope value in many controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

In angularjs when using directive how to apply the scope(isolated scope) value update into many controller.

For example:

I have many templates in view page:

1. left menu template
2. top menu template
3. right content template.

the above things using ui-router plugin.
In this scenario  right content have the controller name is **ordersController.**

Left menu template:

```
<a ng-custom-click  data="data" href="#/order"> Orders </a>
```

List  
.. etc.

```
app.controller('myapp', function($scope){

  $scope.data = {
            list : true,
            details : false,
            test : "rk controller"
        };
}
```

Directive code:

```
app.directive('ngCustomClick', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        replace : false,
        controller : 'ordersController',
        scope : {
            data : '='
        },
        link : function(scope, el, attrs) {
            el.bind('click', function(e) {
                scope.data = {
                 list : false,
                 details : true,
                 test : "abcd directive"
              };
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here ordercontroller is no relationship with left menu template.

So when click the link means the scope.data values need to change in ordercontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope that won't work.

For each directive you're using, a new controller with his own $scope wil be created. So they don't share datas. You need to share them using a service

Here is a working snippet

```js
    var app = angular.module("app",[]);
    app.service('myService', function(){
       this.data = {
                list : true,
                details : false,
                test : "rk controller"
            };
      return this;
    });
    app.controller('myapp2', function($scope, myService){

      $scope.dataOrders = myService.data;
      //optionnal if you want to save change from you order to the service
      $scope.$watch('dataOrders', function(newValue){
          myService.data = newValue;
      });
      // if service's data change resync it
      $scope.$watch(function(){return myService.data;}, function(newValue){
           $scope.dataOrders = newValue;
      });
    }
    );
    app.directive('ngCustomClick', function(myService) {
        return {
            restrict : 'A',
            replace : false,
            scope : {
               
            },
            link : function(scope, el, attrs) {
                el.bind('click', function(e) {
                    myService.data = {
                     list : false,
                     details : true,
                     test : "abcd directive"
                  };
                  scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        };
      });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app">
      <div>
          <a ng-custom-click href="#/order"> Orders </a> 
     </div>
     <div ng-controller="myapp2">
        Orders : {{dataOrders}} 
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.  <a ng-custom-click  data="data" href="#/order"> Orders </a> this code available in left menu. but i need to change the values in ordersController.

Comment: You meant your orders controller is somewhere else in your page ?

Comment: yes. no relationship in left menu html. I attached my code here. but the code its not work .  http://plnkr.co/edit/yYoXo63cQy66d061xFnT?p=preview

Comment: I understand your code. But in my case little different. Please help me I don;t have idea. now updated my all code. http://plnkr.co/edit/yYoXo63cQy66d061xFnT?p=preview

Comment: I edited my post, this time as you can see the controller is declared somewhere else the directive is used. As i said in my original post, controller are instanciated for each time they're used, so you can't use htme like this, you have to use a service to share data and watch for changes.